# Problem with displaying results from search form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I building an application for ads/properties in Laravel. I have a search form with filters that are checkboxes. I am having a problem when I select two options from the same request for example supply, demand that are `PropertyBidAsk` I get only results from demand and not both, also I would like to keep both checked after form submission. Supply and demand are values in the category column in the categories table. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

**CategoryController.php:**

```
public function search(Request $request, Property $property)
{
    $category = $property->category;

    $query = Property::query();

    if ($request->has('propertyBidAsk')) {
        $request->get('propertyBidAsk');
    }

    if ($request->propertyBidAsK == 'supply' && $request->propertyBidAsk== 'demand') {
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->propertyBidAsk . '%');
        });
    } elseif ($request->propertyBidAsk == 'supply') {
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . 'supply' . '%');
        });
    } else if ($request->propertyBidAsk == 'demand') {
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . 'demand' . '%');
        });
    }

    $results = $query->paginate(6);

    return view('search', compact('category', 'results', 'request'));
}
```

**search.blade.php:**

```
<div class="col-md-2 mb-6">
    <h5>Payment Method</h4>
    <div class="d-block my-3">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input id="supply" name="propertyBidAsk" value="supply" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if(old('propertyBidAsk', $request->propertyBidAsk ?? 'default') === 'supply') checked @endif>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="supply">supply</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input id="demand" name="propertyBidAsk" value="demand" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if(old('propertyBidAsk', $request->propertyBidAsk ?? 'default') === 'demand') checked @endif>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="demand">demand</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$request->propertyBidAsK == 'supply' && $request->propertyBidAsk== 'demand'` How could a single string possibly have two distinct values?

Comment: maybe you mean `||` instead of `&&` ?

Comment: @Jerodev I know, but I tried everything and nothing works. This is just for someone to get the idea of what I'm trying to do and to help me if can. I don't know how to solve this

Comment: Maybe you can remove your if condition and just put this $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->propertyBidAsk . '%');

Comment: and try to use `dd($request->propertyBidAsk);` if your request has the right value you want

Comment: @Jovs With || is the same and when I dd I get only one value and I need both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the multi select output with same name attr, update name of your checkbox input to propertyBidAsk[] as array. You will get input array.

```
<input id="supply" name="propertyBidAsk[]" value="supply" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if(old('propertyBidAsk', $request->propertyBidAsk ?? 'default') === 'supply') checked @endif>


<input id="demand" name="propertyBidAsk[]" value="demand" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if(old('propertyBidAsk', $request->propertyBidAsk ?? 'default') === 'demand') checked @endif>
```

In controller will get the value by.

```
public function search(Request $request, Property $property)
{
    $category = $property->category;

    $query = Property::query();

    if ($request->has('propertyBidAsk')) {
        $request->get('propertyBidAsk');
    }


    $propertyBidAsk = $request->input('propertyBidAsk'); //$propertyBidAsk will get in array

    if (in_array('supply', $propertyBidAsk)  && in_array('demand', $propertyBidAsk)){
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%demand%')->orWhere('category', 'like', '%supply%')
        });
    } else if(in_array('supply', $propertyBidAsk)){
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . 'supply' . '%');
        });
    } else  if(in_array('demand', $propertyBidAsk)){
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . 'demand' . '%');
        });
    }

    $results = $query->paginate(6);

    return view('search', compact('category', 'results', 'request'));
}
```

Comment: I get this error now  'Array to string conversion'.

Comment: For multi checkbox need to pass the name attr with array. print_r the  $propertyBidAsk you will get the result based on checked value

Comment: It works now I get correct results. Just my checkboxes don't remain checked after submission. How to solve that? I will accept your answer of course. Thank you

Comment: you have need to change the @if(old('propertyBidAsk', $request->propertyBidAsk ?? 'default') === 'supply') checked @endif>

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196691/discussion-between-shivendra-singh-and-gacho).

Answer (score 1):

As @Shivendra Singh answer you can do that and you can do this also

```
<input id="supply" name="propertyBidAsk1" value="supply" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if(old('propertyBidAsk', $request->propertyBidAsk ?? 'default') === 'supply') checked @endif>


<input id="demand" name="propertyBidAsk2" value="demand" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if(old('propertyBidAsk', $request->propertyBidAsk ?? 'default') === 'demand') checked @endif>
```

You see you can't have same name in an form element it will always get the first value.

then in you controller

```
if (!empty($request->propertyBidAsK1) && !empty($request->propertyBidAsk2) {
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->propertyBidAsk1 . '%')
                  ->orWhere('category', 'like', '%' . $request->propertyBidAsk2 . '%');
        });
    } elseif (!empty($request->propertyBidAsk1)) {
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . 'supply' . '%');
        });
    } else if (!empty($request->propertyBidAsk2)) {
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . 'demand' . '%');
        });
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: With this it keeps both checkboxes checked but I get only results from supply and not demand